# Morningstar secId computation or ISIN mapping?

Tags: websites, securities, morningstar-star-rating

[Morningstar](https://www.morningstar.com/) seem to have a particular identifier for stocks and funds, which is called a `SecId`.

> The Morningstar® SecId is a 10 character alpha numeric code. Each
>   individual investment is assigned a SecId when it is added to the
>   Morningstar® Database.

Does someone knows how it is computed, or which algorithm it uses ? Can it be mapped or linked to a SEDOL, a CUSIP or an ISIN code?

Example :

The fund "Magellan C" has ISIN `FR0000292278`, but morningstar.co.uk maps this to SecId `F0GBR04QCJ` in the url.

http://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04QCJ

Thanks

Comment: It says the SecId is "assigned" rather than derived, and 10 alphanumerics is too small a space to represent arbitrary ISINs algorithmically, so I'd assume it is just an arbitrary database key.

Comment: As the identifier isn't anywhere on the page, it is most probably an url differentiator and nothing more. Moreover they gain no benefit by doing so, as they would have to convert it back to ISIN/SEDOL/CUSIP to so anything.

Comment: Its not a URL differentiator, its a "Morningstar SecID"

Comment: See API documentation here https://addin.morningstarcommodity.com/media/Morningstar%20Direct%20Add-In%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide.pdf